# asp:listbox control customization

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, information-retrieval

Im doing this Information retrival search engine that search in Doc files for certain terms using [Lucine.net](http://lucene.apache.org/) Every thing is going fine I get the results search results in an asp:listbox control.

I managed to get the name of the file and the path of it as shown in the figuer below:

[image]

```
// Using      
 lst_searchResult.Items.Add(doc.Get("title"));
 lst_searchResult.Items.Add(doc.Get("path"));
```

I would like to perform more operation on the listbox selected Items such as

1. ( Download Document ) using a button .
2. ( Send link Via Email ).

I'm not an expert to be honest with ASP.net , can you please guide me ?

thank you

Comment: what's the problem? what did you try? Here doubts are solved... but C# isn't taught.. I think.

Comment: I tried to search for what asp:listbox is capable for but couldnt find what I'm tring to do.

Comment: I think its better to use `gridview` or `datalist` for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `asp:listbox` is redered as an `<select>` html control. The appearance of the select control is dertermined by the browser you are using. The only customization option is to set the border/colors/scrollbar of this control.

If you want a more interactive appearance use the `asp:listview` control. With that you can control how one row of the list is rendered. So you can add buttons, links, etc.

In code you define a DataStructure like

```
class SearchResult
{
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public string Path {get; set;}
}
```

And then bind a `List<SearchResult>` to the listview control.

The markup for the ListView could look something like this:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" ></tr>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><a href='<%#Eval("Path") %>'><%#Eval("Title") %></a></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

This link shows a bunch of examples on how to use the ListView control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx